# Fastlane crashes when running Match command: Error accessing file, this might be due to fastlane's directory handling

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-m1, fastlane, cicd

I'm currently trying to store my certs and provisioning profiles in a S3 Bucket.

When I run the `fastlane match development/appstore` command I get the following log

```
 Error accessing file, this might be due to fastlane's directory handling
[16:31:19]: Check out https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#directory-behavior for more details

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.208.0/libexec/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.131.3/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:67:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/folders/td/2ks8dv9s3fl42qzrdmlg9r0w0000gn/T/d20220719-23830-ooiwmv/cert-test/ (Errno::ENOENT)
```

This is how my .env file looks like

```
MATCH_PASSWORD=1234
MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD=1234
MATCH_S3_BUCKET=mobile-application-certs
MATCH_S3_REGION=us-east-1
MATCH_S3_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
MATCH_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
```

And this is how my Matchfile looks like

```
storage_mode("s3")
s3_bucket(ENV["MATCH_S3_BUCKET"])
s3_region(ENV["MATCH_S3_REGION"])
s3_access_key(ENV["MATCH_S3_ACCESS_KEY"])
s3_secret_access_key(ENV["MATCH_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])

type("appstore")
username("test@test.com")
app_identifier("org.example.asd.com")
```

NOTE: Worth to mention that it works fine when storing the certs/provisioning profiles with Git.